# Programmatically filled out dijit inputbox's value is not stored without activating manually the inputbox (javascript)

Tags: javascript, dojo, inputbox

This is my first (javascript) development, so i'm in the dark. I'm developing an out of the box widget, and i couldn't find the data's route to the server, because it's to flexible and complex, so i tought i put the value into the dijit inputbox simply. 
itemId is the data. 
Btw:the popup widget's inputbox has an automatically assigned id, what is incrementing with every opening. The increment method solved my problem.
Unfortunately this problem solving is not working properly, because the user has to click into the inputbox before submitting the form. If it's not happening, the data is not stored.

Any workaround for this? Or could somebody tell me why this is happening? Security? (i want to hide this section if it's working)

```
      var itemID= this._editWidget.map.itemInfo.item.id;     
      var textBoxNumber = this.increment();


      dojo.connect(dijit.byId('dijit_form_ValidationTextBox_'+(textBoxNumber+2)), 'onChange', function () {
        var inputBoxId = "dijit_form_ValidationTextBox_"+ textBoxNumber;
        var mapid=dijit.byId(inputBoxId).attr("value");      
        var update = mapid.replace(mapid, itemID);
        dojo.byId(inputBoxId).value = update;
      });

    increment: (function(n) {
      return function() {
        n += 4;
        return n;
      }
    }(-3)),
```

The dynamic html:

```
<div class="dijitReset dijitInputField dijitInputContainer"><input 
class="dijitReset dijitInputInner" data-dojo-attach-point="textbox,focusNode" 
autocomplete="off" type="text" tabindex="0" id="dijit_form_ValidationTextBox_1" 
maxlength="50" aria-required="false" value="" aria-invalid="false"></div>

<input class="dijitReset dijitInputInner" 
data-dojo-attach-point="textbox,focusNode" 
autocomplete="off" type="text" tabindex="0" 
id="dijit_form_ValidationTextBox_1" 
maxlength="50" aria-required="false" 
value="" aria-invalid="false">
```

Answer (score 0):

I tought it' more difficult. I just focus my target inputbox after adding the mod, and defocus it right after, nothing is visible for the user.

```
define(['dijit/focus'],
function (focusUtil){
dojo.connect(dijit.byId('dijit_form_ValidationTextBox_'+(textBoxNumber+2)), 'onChange', function () {
        var inputBoxId = "dijit_form_ValidationTextBox_"+ textBoxNumber;
        var mapid=dijit.byId(inputBoxId).attr("value");      
        var update = mapid.replace(mapid, itemID);
        dojo.byId(inputBoxId).value = update;
        focusUtil.focus(dojo.byId(inputBoxId));
        focusUtil.curNode && focusUtil.curNode.blur();
})
```

Same like:`getElementbyId('someId').focus();`